# Question about Smiley Face notation

Tags: category-theory, notation

I am reading David Spivak's "Categoty Theory For The Sciences" and in section 2.1.2.9 he uses some notation that I don't understand. He uses a Smiley Face to represent an element in a Set. Is he being cute or is it something else? Below is the text (I use a 'SF' instead of the smiley face glyph because my MathJax skills are not good).

> *Notation 2.1.2.9*: Let X be a set and x $\in$ X an element. There is a function {SF} $\rightarrow$ X that sends SF $\mapsto$ x. We say that
>   this function *represents* x element of X. We may denote it *x*:{SF}
>   $\rightarrow$ X.

What does it mean to send SF $\mapsto$ X? Is he saying that the function {SF} $\rightarrow$ X sends any set with one element to X? Thanks.

Comment: I found it online at [this link](https://archive.org/details/cattheory/page/n35), and the smiley faces are missing! So it must be some weird character unrecognised by the rendering software. My bet would be on the empty set $\emptyset$.

Comment: @TonyK does the figure on the right page render for you?  It is clearly a smiley face that appears for me in the figure, though the paras do have a missing space for the symbol on my computer as well for that link

Comment: Okay.  I think I see what he means.  He's saying that if we have a set of elements, say a set of pigs, and I want to talk about one of the pigs.  Instead of picking up a muddy 300 lb pig with shit on its hoofs and throwing it in your lap every time I talk about it, I can see "Let's talk about this pig named 'Napoleon'". There is function from $\{'Napoleon'\}\to \{pigs\}$ so that $'Napoleon\mapsto $ the pig called Napoleon. ...This function allows us to *represent* elements and there is one representation for each and every element in a set.....At least that's what I *think* he is saying.

Comment: @JMoravitz: Yes, I do see the smiley face inside the square. So it looks like the smileys are deliberate.

Comment: $f$ does not send any set with one element to $X$, it sends the one element of $\{SF\}$ to $x$. That is, the domain of $f$ is $\{SF\}$, the codomain is $X$, and the function satisfies $f(SF)=x$.

Comment: Oh... ne'mine...  I *think* he's saying for any $ginkydink$ and any $x \in X$ there is *always* an implicit function from $\{ginkydink\}\to X$ via $ginkydink\mapsto x$  and that function itself is a *respresentation* of $x$.... I think this is akin to the category theory idea that "everything is sets". Any actual *thing* is represented but a function that maps a single item (what item is irrelevent-- it's the function (which is sets; everything is sets) that matters) to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that $f$ is a function from a set $A$ to a set $B$ can be expressed as $f\colon A\to B$ (or, if we do not want to name the function, just $A\to B$). However, this does not specify *how* the function determines an element of $B$ for every given element of $A$. To express this, we either write something like $f(a)=b$, or we use a different arrow and write $a\mapsto b$. Of course, do completely describe $f$, we must coever every element of $A$. Fortunately, if $A=\{☺\}$ is just a singleton, specifying the result for the single element $☺$ suffices. So we could define $f$ by saying $f(☺)=x$, or equivalently (but without the need to have a name $f$ for the function) by saying $☺\mapsto x$.

Answer (score 1):

He picked {SF} as a set of some elements (presumably smiley faces). The Exercise 2.1.2.10 with solution that follows the notation gives more clarity. It uses $f:Y\rightarrow X$ instead of $f:\{SF\}\rightarrow Y$.

Comment: i think $\{SF\}$ is set of *one* element: SF.

Comment: yea ... most likely it's a singleton. https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Category_Theory_for_the_Sciences.html?id=CwfjBAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score 1):

He is defining something that I would call ”$A$-valued point“. He is considering an arbitrary set $\lbrace :) \rbrace$ of cardinality $1$. You can literally put anything inside. It does not matter (that is probably why he chose something like a smiley). Specifying an element $a \in A$ is now the same as a function $\lbrace :) \rbrace \rightarrow A$, namely by sending $:)$ to the element $a$. Furthermore, he then represents the image $f(a)$ of an element $a$ under a map $f \colon A \rightarrow B$ as $:) \mapsto a \mapsto b$, i.e. as a composition. This makes sense as you would define a map by specifying where a point $a$ is sent to and we just discussed how we can specify a point.

To define a point like this is something that one does in algebraic geometry for example. The idea is that one can understand isomorphism classes of an object $X$  by understanding all morphisms out of or into $X$ by the so-called Yoneda lemma. Therefore it can be very useful to define points as morphisms.